# Is there a shortcut for opening a second buffer with a vertical split in Aquamacs?

Tags: text-editor, emacs

I'd like to have two buffers open side by side in Aquamacs. Is there a shortcut for doing this?

I know that C-x 2 opens them in a vertical stack, I'd like to have them arranged horizontally though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `split-window-horizontally` which is bound to C-x 3.